# While Loop not working correctly in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, beautifulsoup

```
    r = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    while True:
        if soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'function'}):
            break
        time.sleep(3)
        print ('Not Found... Trying again.')

    print ('Found soup...')
```

The `while` loop when `soup.find_all` is not found should retry until it finds `soup.find_all`. When `soup.find_all` is present in `r.content` it should normally print 'Found soup...' however its not doing this, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you need to move the lines that get and parse the HTML to inside the while loop?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think that might solve the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if a website updates it code it will find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That loop doesn't make sense. Either `find_all` will find all in one call, or it will not find anything and you will have an infinite loop (since nothing will ever change in the loop then).

So the solution is simply to *not* have a loop, and only use a normal `if-else`:

```
r = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
if soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'function'}):
    print ('Found soup...')
else:
    print ('Not Found... Trying again.')
```

---

If you intend to re-fetch the HTML from the source, then you need to put *all* of the code inside the loop:

```
while True:
    r = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    if soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'function'}):
        print ('Found soup...')
        break
    else:
        print ('Not Found... Trying again.')
        time.sleep(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all(<HTML attribute>)` returns a list of instances to your queried attribute, or an empty list if none are found. You don't need to put it in a loop. So you can just do this instead:

```
r = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
instances = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'function'}):

if len(instances) == 0:
    print("No divs with class 'function'")
else:
    print("Yay, it was a success!")
```